# What is the best way to coalesce two values, if the first value is Null?

Tags: evaluation

I want to set a variable to a value, and have a default value in case the previous value is Null. Basically it would act like a Coalesce statement in SQL. I have not been able to find a succinct way to do this. The best way is to do:
`If[!TrueQ[value=Null],value,0]`

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `value/.Null->0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all the ways I can think of, the first two of which are the most concise and in my opinion the most Mathematica-l:

1. `x = Replace[value, Null -> default]`, in a manner similar to @John Doty's comment above, which suggests `x = value /. Null -> default`; however, `/.` is `ReplaceAll`, and so will also replace any occurrences of `Null` anywhere inside the expression. E.g. `{1, f[Null]}} /. Null -> default` will produce `{1, f[default]}}` (if `f` is undefined), whereas `Replace` only considers the whole expression (or a certain level, if we had specified it).
2. Define a function `ReplaceNull[Null] = default; ReplaceNull[x_] := x`; then we have `x = ReplaceNull[value]`.
3. `x = Switch[value, Null, default, _, value]`, which, like the above two, uses pattern matching
4. A more concise version of what you wrote: `x = If[value == Null, default, value]`.